# function isnt working 'cause of else if statement

Tags: jquery

I've a function with just an if else and an else if, but for some reason my else if isn't working,
in the chrome console it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'`

jQuery code

```
function check_mlastname() {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
    var mlastname = $('#newmlastname').val();
    if (pattern.test(mlastname) && mlastname !== '') {
        $('#error').hide();
        $('#newmlastname').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #34F458');
    } else {
        $('#error').html('Solo puede contener letras');
        $('#error').show();
        $('#newmlastname').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #F90A0A');
        error_mlastname = true;
    }else if(!$('#newmlastname').val()) {
        $('#error').html('No puede dejar el campo vacío!');
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have an `else if` after an `else`. Also, it would seem that `mlastname !== ''` is accomplishing almost the same thing as `!$('#newmlastname').val()`.

Comment: @TylerRoper but if i put my else if before else, the else will take the if or the else if statement? :-(

Comment: you can't have `else if` after `else`! `else` is the last option always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `else if` before `else` :

```
function check_mlastname() {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
    var mlastname = $('#newmlastname').val();

    if (pattern.test(mlastname) && mlastname !== '') {
        $('#error').hide();
        $('#newmlastname').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #34F458');
     } else if(!$('#newmlastname').val()) {
        $('#error').html('No puede dejar el campo vacío!');
     } else {
        $('#error').html('Solo puede contener letras');
        $('#error').show();
        $('#newmlastname').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #F90A0A');
        error_mlastname = true;
    }
}
```